# Type Error issues converting List of objects into class structure from Json

Tags: json, dynamic, flutter, dart, typeerror

I am trying to convert a list of objects into a class structure from JSON.  I've run into some type-errors that I can't seem to get around.

I've set up some methods to convert each piece of the objects into and from JSON and individually they work great and I've had no issues.  The problem is when I try doing it with a list of all the pieces together.

Where my code gets the error:

```
    var temp = json.decode(response.body);
    var shifts = ShiftList.fromJson(temp); // This is where it breaks
```

ShiftList Class:

```
   class ShiftList {
  List<Shift> shifts;
  ShiftList({
    this.shifts,
  });

  addShift(Shift shift){
    if(shifts == null){
      shifts = [shift];
    }else{
      shifts.add(shift);
    }
  }

  factory ShiftList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ShiftList(
      shifts: _toObjectList(json['Shifts'], (e) => Shift.fromJson(e)),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'Shifts': _fromList(shifts, (e) => e.toJson()),
    };
  }

}

List _fromList(data, Function(dynamic) toJson) {
  if (data == null) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var element in data) {
    var value;
    if (element != null) {
      value = toJson(element);
    }
    result.add(value);
  }
  return result;
}

List<T> _toObjectList<T>(data, T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJson) {
  if (data == null) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = <T>[];
  for (var element in data) {
    T value;
    if (element != null) {
      value = fromJson(element as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }
    result.add(value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Shift Class:

```
class Shift {
  String Name;
  String AccountID;
  String Identifier;
  UserList UserVal;
  ReportList Reports;
  TaskList Tasks;
  String Scheduling;
  String ShiftManagerCode;

  Shift({
    this.AccountID,
    this.Name,
    this.ShiftManagerCode,
    this.Identifier,
    this.UserVal,
    this.Reports,
    this.Tasks,
    this.Scheduling,
  });

  factory Shift.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Shift(
      AccountID: json['AccountID'] as String,
      Identifier: json['Identifier'] as String,
      Name: json['ShiftName'] as String,
      ShiftManagerCode: json['ShiftManagerCode'] as String,
      UserVal: json['UserVal'] as UserList,
      Reports: json['Reports'] as ReportList,
      Tasks: json['Tasks'] as TaskList,
      Scheduling: json['Scheduling'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'ShiftName': this.Name,
      'AccountID': this.AccountID,
      'Identifier': this.Identifier,
      'ShiftManagerCode': this.ShiftManagerCode,
      'UserVal': this.UserVal,
      'Reports': this.Reports,
      'Tasks': this.Tasks,
      'Scheduling': this.Scheduling,
    };
  }
}
```

and finally, the UserList class where it gets the error:

```
class UserList {
  List<UserObject> users;
  UserList({
    this.users,
  });

  addUser(UserObject user){
    if(users == null){
      users = [user];
    }else{
      users.add(user);
    }
  }

  factory UserList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserList(
      users: _toObjectList(json['UserVal'], (e) => UserObject.fromJson(e)),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'UserVal': _fromList(users, (e) => e.toJson()),
    };
  }

}

List _fromList(data, Function(dynamic) toJson) {
  if (data == null) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var element in data) {
    var value;
    if (element != null) {
      value = toJson(element);
    }
    result.add(value);
  }
  return result;
}

List<T> _toObjectList<T>(data, T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJson) {
  if (data == null) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = <T>[];
  for (var element in data) {
    T value;
    if (element != null) {
      value = fromJson(element as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }
    result.add(value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I expect it place the JSON object into the class structure I have in place.  The specific error I get is the following:

```
flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'UserList' in typecast
```

the variable temp from my first code snippet is the following:

```
{
    "Shifts": [
        {
            "UserVal": [
                {
                    "UID": "test",
                    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
                    "Phone": "0000000000",
                    "Name": "James"
                },
                {
                    "UID": "test",
                    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
                    "Phone": "0000000000",
                    "Name": "Jacob"
                }
            ],
            "AccountID": "1295",
            "Identifier": "JhfSC",
            "ShiftManagerCode": "15A4",
            "Reports": [
                {
                    "Quantity": "3",
                    "User": "Jacob",
                    "Supplies": "ItemA",
                    "Subject": "Supplies",
                    "Note": "test"
                }
            ],
            "Scheduling": "EMPTY",
            "ShiftName": "AF 37",
            "Tasks": [
                {
                    "Status": "done",
                    "User": "James",
                    "Description": "Description here",
                    "Name": "TaskName here"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can't just cast it you have to parse it from the json. So instead of json['UserVal'] as UserList. Do       `UserVal:UserList.fromJson(json['UserVal'])`

Comment: I still get a slightly different casting error however after modifying those 3 objects to cast in that manner: ```flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'```

Comment: Added an answer to how you might want to change your fromJson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating new objects that contain your list, just have you shift class contain a property of List.

```
class Shift {
  String Name;
  String AccountID;
  String Identifier;
  List<UserObject> UserVal;
  ReportList Reports; // do same for this
  TaskList Tasks; // do same for this
  String Scheduling;
  String ShiftManagerCode;

  Shift({
    this.AccountID,
    this.Name,
    this.ShiftManagerCode,
    this.Identifier,
    this.UserVal,
    this.Reports,
    this.Tasks,
    this.Scheduling,
  });

  factory Shift.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Shift(
      AccountID: json['AccountID'] as String,
      Identifier: json['Identifier'] as String,
      Name: json['ShiftName'] as String,
      ShiftManagerCode: json['ShiftManagerCode'] as String,
      UserVal: json['UserVal'] == null ? List<UserObject> : (json['UserVal'] as List<Dynamic>).map((dynamic map) => UserObject.fromJson(map)).toList(),
      Reports: json['Reports'] as ReportList,
      Tasks: json['Tasks'] as TaskList,
      Scheduling: json['Scheduling'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'ShiftName': this.Name,
      'AccountID': this.AccountID,
      'Identifier': this.Identifier,
      'ShiftManagerCode': this.ShiftManagerCode,
      'UserVal': this.UserVal,
      'Reports': this.Reports,
      'Tasks': this.Tasks,
      'Scheduling': this.Scheduling,
    };
  }
}
```

So now you can convert directly inside your from Json. You will have to do extra work in toJson to have it map correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without diving too deep into your implementation, `json.decode(response.body)` is returning a `List<dynamic>` type. You are anticipating a `List<Map<String, dynamic>` so you need to call `.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()` on the list.